# Saving CSV in UTF-8 on Mac

Tags: core-data, utf-8, swift2, xcode7

I am having problems to save a CSV file for Core Data using my Mac, works if I save in Windows computer but not in the MAC. I am using Excel. Every time I run the CSV file saved in MAC there are different errors in the Xcode.

Comment: ?? what is the role of XCode and / or Swift in your approach ( you wrote that you are using Excel to export your data )

Comment: Yes, I build the database in excel two columns, save as .csv file, to be read by xcode.

Comment: in that case, please, show us some example of your data and what kind of trouble you experienced with XCode and / or your Swift's code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my experience when you save CSV files in a Mac computer it is always a mess. I had several problems dug in the forums and realize only could save CSV in PC with windows. 
If you are using UTF-8 in your coreData you can workaround with this, I am doing this for some time and never had problem again in my Mac.
The way I do:

1. Save the .CSV file (comma delimited) in Excel.
2. Open the .CSV file with (http://www.sublimetext.com/2
3. File > Save with Encoding > choose the one you want.
4. Done.
   If you have to edit or open the file in Excel, you have to save in Sublime Text 2 again before you drag to your Xcode project.

   Forget Windows computers :)

   Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: My tool is going to use excel for the data from user.
but this step will make hard mac users to make csv for the tool.
Mac Excel doesn't support the encoding when we save?